# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch (Angular)

Tags: angular, heroku

I'm developing an Angular 7 application and trying to connect it to Heroku (i'm new to Heroku)

When i try to run the application on Heroku i get the following error:
[image]

I do not have a server side. only frontend.

How can i resolve this?

[EDIT]:

the `server.js` seems to work now.

Issue now is get the below error and the web page does not load:
`Refused to load the image 'https://games-dos.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

I do have the favico defined under `angular.json`
[image]

and I'm using is in my HTML
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are developing a static website. A web server is not required. Static websites can be hosted on e.g. GitHub pages.

A web server can serve static content but I question if it makes sense. 
When writing the logic for the web server you listen on the `$PORT`. It is an environment variable supplied by Heroku. You did not bind to that hence the error.

If I were you I would revise the idea. If you still want to host on Heroku you'll need to do something along the lines of this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build'))); // <-- this is pointing to your static html, css and js files

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```

Name that `server.js`. Create a new entry in `scripts` in `package.json`: `"startserver": "node server.js"`. Create a Procfile with the content `web: npm run startserver`.

Comment: Thx for your respond. I've tried what you've suggested but i still having some issue. I've edited the original question with more information. i'll appreciate if you can have a look.

Comment: There might be a fault in my script. Try `web: npm run startserver` in `Procfile`

Comment: seems this part is working now.
I'm getting another error regarding favico.ico (i'm editing my question again) which causes the page not to load.

Comment: That's an entirely different error. I can't help you with that one. Try creating a new StackOverflow question